# Adding widget to screen using configuration Activity

Tags: android, android-widget

Currently, after the user drags and drops the widget on to their screen, my configuration Activity is launched. Now to get the Widget to actually be added to the screen, in the config activity I do:

```
Intent resultValue = new Intent();
resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
finish();
```

Basically, I'm not sure how else to return the `RESULT_OK` result set in setResult() back to the caller without calling finish();. Currently this is in the Activities onCreate() so the Activity closes as soon as its launched. I dont want to have to add an "Ok" button for the user to press to then call finish() so the result is returned.

I need the widget to be added to the screen no matter what after the user drags+drops it onto their screen. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to call `finish()` right away, you can set the result in `onCreate()` and then let the Activity continue to run. I'm not sure what the benefit would be, but it's perfectly OK.

**EDIT**

Since you can't capture the home button press and you can't prevent the user from switching apps, the only other suggestions I have are the following:

1. Don't use a configuration activity in your `<appqidget-provider>`. Instead place the widget on screen with some default configuration and have the user click on it to launch the Activity to modify the configuration.
2. Call `finish()` in `onStop()`. If the user navigates away or presses Home, you should get the `onStop()` callback and you can simply close the activity. The user might try to go back to it though, so maybe it's worth using `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` for that activity in your manifest.

Comment: Yes, but if I dont call finish(), the result isnt returned, which causes the Widget to not be added to the screen. So If I just set the result in `onCreate()`, and the user presses the home button or navigates away for any reason, the Widget doesnt get added.

Comment: @Orbit Normally these activities call `finish()` later based on user input. If that's still not good enough for you, see my edit above.

Comment: Yes, I dont want the user to have to click a button just so I can call `finish()`. Also, do you think calling `finish()` in `onPause()` would be better then `onStop()`? I've realized this activity is more of a settings/first use help activity then a true configuration activity, as no specific user configuration is needed to get the Widget working, so I may just be using the config activity incorrectly in this context. Also, do you know of anyway to return the result set in `setResult()` back to the caller WITHOUT using `finish()`? Is that possible?

Comment: @Orbit No, you cannot return the result to the caller without calling finish. If it's not actually a configuration activity, then in my opinion don't use it as one. I recommend `onStop()` because many things can pause your Activity even while it is visible..